# Error for bar chart in matplotlib python 3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, bioinformatics

I am trying to make a bar graph (from mean values) that includes error bars (from standard deviation values) using matplotlib, but have been running into an error saying:

```
'Rectangle' object has no property 'labels'
```

and if I remove this line:

```
'Rectangle' object has no property 'rotation'
```

Some help and clarification into what is happening would be great! Here is an example of what I have so far below:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6]
list3=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
x = range(len(list1))
y = list1 #contains mean values in list
z = list2 #contains std values in list
l=list3 #contains label names
plt.bar(x, y, yerr=z, color='green', rotation='vertical', label=l)  
plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: plt.bar does not take a rotation argument, so you should take that out to make your code work.  As far as label is concerned, it is used to provide a single name for all your green bars in the plot's legend if you call the plt.legend() method before you show the plot.  What is it that you are trying to achieve?  There is probably a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6]
list3=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
x = range(len(list1))
y = list1 #contains mean values in list
z = list2 #contains std values in list
l=list3 #contains label names
rects = plt.bar(x, y, yerr=z, color='green', label=l)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.bar_label(rects)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6]
list3=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
x = range(len(list1))
y = list1 #contains mean values in list
z = list2 #contains std values in list
l=list3 #contains label names
rects = plt.barh(x, y, xerr=z, color='green', label=l)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.bar_label(rects)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can I show the error value, at the top of the bar ?

Comment: @0Knowledge change this line `ax.bar_label(rects, list2)` to label with list2.

Answer (score 0):

The errors result from `plt.bar()` not knowing the keywords `rotation` and `label`, so these arguments are passed on to the lower level plotting functions, but apparently those can't handle them either.

To plot a horizontal bar chart, you can use `plt.barh()`. Note that you then want to pass the error values as `xerr` rather than `yerr`. The keyword for the labels is `tick_label`.

```py
plt.barh(x, y, xerr=z, color='green', tick_label=l)
```

[image: horizontal bar plot]